# after group by I want to do aggregation on those groups with more than 5 members in python, how should I do that?

Tags: python, filter, group-by, count, pandas-groupby

I have Value of [Energy Cost Saving Program dataset](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Value-of-Energy-Cost-Savings-Program-Savings-for-B/bug8-9f3g)

And I want to answer this question:
Considering only NTAs with at least 5 listed businesses, what is the average total savings and the total jobs created for each NTA?

So I used the following code for the first parts:

```
df['NTA_mod']=df['NTA'].str.split('-')
df=df.explode('NTA_mod').reset_index(drop=True)

df_NTA_grp=df.groupby(['NTA_mod'])
```

now I have to pick those with NTA greater than 5 and I used following code

```
df.groupby('NTA_mod').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

However, I don't get any response and I don't know how to continue to answer the question. How should I pick those NTA with businesses with at least 5 businesses?
is my approach correct?
If yes now how should I aggregate to get mean and sum for next step?

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the right direction. Use [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) method to get mean and sum. `aggregate` can perform different operations on different columns.

```py
df_ge_5 = df_NTA_grp.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)

df_ge_5.groupby('NTA_mod').agg({ 
    'Total Savings': 'mean',
    'Job created': 'sum',
})
# Or, renaming columns with named aggregation
aggn = {
    'Average Total Savings': ('Total Savings', 'mean'),
    'Total Jobs Created': ('Job created','sum'),
}
df_ge_5.groupby('NTA_mod').agg(**aggn)
```